# How to use json to config tests assertions?

Tags: json, unit-testing, reflection

I know the question is a bit vague. Basically I want to use json to config test case and test case has different assertions. The test is doing a http call and getting a http response. All the validations are against the content of the response (the response content is in json format)
e.g. a json can be

```
{
   "TestName": "SampleTest",
   "Assertions": [
      { "Field": "response.statuscode",
        "Value": 200
      },
      { "Field": "response.jsoncontent.username",
        "Value": "jack"
      },
      { "Field": "response.jsoncontent.address[0]",
        "Value": "White House"
      }]
}
```

Then in the code, (no matter what language), I can use something like

```
assert.areEqual(response.statuscode, 200)
assert.areEqual(response.json.username, "jack")
assert.areEqual(response.json.address[0], "White House")
```

Is there an elegant way to do this except recursively using reflection to get fields of the resposne object?